# Access JSON key value dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my json which is dynamic. I want to access 'bf' key in the json ,  'xxxxxx20160929' and 'yyy813AI20160929' keys are dynamic but json structure will be the same

```
{
  "resultData": [
    {
      "a": "124",
      "b": "0",
      "c": "0",
      "flc_schedu": {
          "e": "6",
          "f": "en",
          "xxxxxx20160929": [
            {"ID": "yyyyyyyy" },
            {"ID": "fffff"}
         ]
      },
      "fareDetails": {
        "xxxxxx20160929": {
          "yyy813AI20160929": {
            "O": {
              "AD": {
                "bf": "2527"
                    }
                 }
          }
        }
            }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is how I tried

```
response.resultData[0].fareDetails[Object.keys(response.resultData[0].fareDetails)[0]]
```

If I try as above I can able to access dynamically up to "xxxxxx20160929" key, but I can't able get how to reach up to "bf" key dynamicaly.

Comment: you just need to append **.yyy813AI20160929.O.AD.bf**

Comment: @Pat : yyy813AI20160929 key is dynamic, its not possible to do like u given

Comment: Try this: data.resultData[0].fareDetails.xxxxxx20160929['yyy813AI20160929'].O.AD.bf

Comment: @Samuel : : yyy813AI20160929 key is dynamic, we cannot keep it static as u given

Comment: that is simple - you can do this 
`var data = ` **<<< access dynamically up to "xxxxxx20160929" >>>**
then do this (provided there is only 1 child agreed for xxxxxx20160929)
`var value;
for (var key in data) {
   value = key;
   }`

thenyou  have your bf value - `data.value.O.AD.bf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference an object using the array syntax.

```
var one = 'xxxxxx20160929';
var two = 'yyy813AI20160929';
data.resultData[0].fareDetails[one][two].O.AD.bf;
```

UPDATE:

This code assumes there is only one dynamic object at each layer.

```
var one = Object.keys(data.resultData[0].fareDetails)[0];
var two = Object.keys(data.resultData[0].fareDetails[one])[0];
var thing = data.resultData[0].fareDetails[one][two].O.AD.bf;
```

Comment: : xxxxxx20160929, yyy813AI20160929 key are dynamic, we cannot keep it static as u given

Comment: Can you sugget how to access "yyy813AI20160929" dynamically

Comment: Do you mean you don't know what the property is named?

Comment: i undestood above way but u kept 'two' variable static and taking 'yyy813AI20160929', i want to know how to take  'yyy813AI20160929' value dynamically from above json

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to get the key dynamically for each layer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBFFromFareDetails(details){
 var bfValues = [];
  for(var k in details.fareDetails){
   // loop over the children of fareDetails
   if( details.fareDetails.hasOwnProperty( k ) ) {
      //each entry in ;fareDetails'
      var itemRoot = details.fareDetails[k]
      for(var k1 in itemRoot){
         // loop over the children of the first unknown item
          if( itemRoot.hasOwnProperty( k1 ) ) {
              //return the bf from the first unknown child
             return itemRoot[k1].O.AD.bf;
          }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

If you call this with `var bf = getBFFromFareDetails(response.resultData[0])`
this will return the value for the first bf in the first child of `fareDetails` and its first child.

You can see a quick example in action here https://jsfiddle.net/tocsoft/5364x2sp/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access up to "xxxxxx20160929" level then create a var to store that level, then use that variable to access the next which you will need to store in a variable, then use both variable to access the key needed.

```
var1 = response.resultData[0].fareDetails)[0];
var2 = response.resultData[0].fareDetails)[0][var1];

response.resultData[0].fareDetails)[0][var1][var2];
```